# Showing that the $2\times2$ complex matrices with trace zero are a subspace over the reals, with another subspace inside it.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So I have the following question

> Let $V$ be the set of all $2\times2$ matrices $A=(a_{ij})$ with complex entries and trace zero. Show that $V$ is a vector space over the field of reals. Let $W$ be the set of all matrices $A=(a_{ij})$ in $V$ such that $a_{21}=-{\bar{a_{12}}}$. Prove that $W$ is a subspace of $V$ and find basis of  $W$.

So firstly to prove that $V$ is a vector space, but how will I prove it over the field of reals? Like the if the entries are complex, then maybe I can write $A\in M_{2\times2}(\mathbb{C})$, and hence I can easily prove $V$ to be vector space by showing the closed addition and scalar multiplication and existence of zero vector. Is it that if I choose $A\in M_{2\times2}(\mathbb{R})$, I will have to write matrix as basis in ${(1,i)}$?. Please help, as I am pretty new in linear algrebra so I lack rigorous proof methods.

Comment: Yes. That's enough, becaulse this is to prove this is subspace of general space of (2x2 ) complex matrices over the field R. Basis is the smallest sets of elements of W wich we need to combine linearly to  make any other matrix from V

Comment: @AdamWrzesiński No, $V$ is **not** a subspace of $A$, because they do not share a scalar field. OP, your argument validates that $V$ would be a vector space if equipped with standard complex scalar multiplication, but some further argument may be necessary to conclude that defining scalar multiplication with reals still produces a vector space (although, it's worth noting that addition between both versions of $V$ would be the same).

Comment: @TheoBendit can you please write an answer, as I really have hard time understanding what you said

Answer (score 0):

This is just an expansion of [my comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4867394/let-v-be-the-set-of-all-2-times2-matrices-a-a-ij-with-complex-entries?noredirect=1#comment10377655_4867394).

Let's consider the following statement:

> Suppose we have a vector space $X$. A subset of $Y$ of $X$ is a subspace if it contains $0$ (or, is just non-empty), and is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. And, every subspace is a vector space in its own right.

Everyone learning linear algebra learns some variation of this statement, either as a definition of subspaces, or a theorem. And, applying this with $X = A$ and $Y = V$, one could certainly see why $V$ would be considered a subspace of $A$.

The problem is, the above statement is missing things: small details that are usually not spelled out explicitly. It's the kind of thing that more experienced people can usually remember without a problem, but will trip up students from time to time.

What's missing above is the field and operations attached to the aforementioned vector spaces. Remember, a vector space is more than a set. A vector space is technically an ordered quadruple: $(X, \Bbb{F}, +, \cdot)$, where $X$ is a set (whose elements we call vectors), $\Bbb{F}$ is a field (whose elements we call scalars), $+$ is a function called vector addition $+ : V \times V \to V$, i.e. taking a pair of vectors and producing another vector, and $\cdot$ is another function called scalar multiplication, where $\cdot : \Bbb{F} \times V \to V$.

There are several axioms that also must be satisfied for a quadruple like this to be a vector space, however the point is, there are three other essential components beyond the set $X$ that define a vector space. We just often abbreviate the vector space $(X, \Bbb{F}, +, \cdot)$ down to the set component $X$, if the other three can be understood from context.

Note that, it's possible to change the scalar field, or change the addition/multiplication operations. The result is a *new* vector space, which still has the same set of vectors. The set doesn't change, but the vector space changes.

It's precisely this context that the highlighted statement omits. So, let's now include the omitted context:

> Suppose we have a vector space $(X, \Bbb{F}, +, \cdot)$. Suppose we have a subset $Y$ of $X$ containing $0$, and closed under addition and scalar multiplication. Let $+_Y : Y \times Y \to Y$ and $\cdot_Y : \Bbb{F} \times Y \to Y$ be the restrictions of $+$ and $\cdot$ respectively, to $Y \times Y$ and $\Bbb{F} \times Y$ respectively. Then we say $(Y, \Bbb{F}, +_Y, \cdot_Y)$ is a subspace of $(X, \Bbb{F}, +, \cdot)$. Moreover, $(Y, \Bbb{F}, +_Y, \cdot_Y)$ is a vector space in its own right.

Here, I've more explicitly outlined all the operations and scalar fields involved. Note that a subspace inherits a restricted version of addition and scalar multiplication from the original vector space. Also, and this is what's most relevant to us, **the subspace has the same field as the vector space**.

What this means is that you cannot validly apply this statement to prove that $V$ is a vector space, using the fact that $A$ is a vector space. This is because $A$ is over $\Bbb{C}$, while $V$ is over $\Bbb{R}$.

So, my recommendation would be to embark on a full proof that $V$ is a vector space, using all the axioms. While there are shortcuts, I think you're not confident enough with the basics yet to use them safely.